# What is the difference between $signed and signed' in verilog?

Tags: logic, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, register-transfer-level

What is the difference between `$signed` and `signed'` in verilog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`signed'()` does not exist in Verilog. It it exists in SystemVerilog.

[IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 6.24.1 *Cast operator*:

> NOTE—The `$signed()` and `$unsigned()` system functions (see 11.7) return the same results as `signed'()` and `unsigned'()`, respectively.

`signed'()` exists as feature with casting operator (`'()`)
`$signed()` exists for compatibility with Verilog